# Generating invoices in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, invoice, invoices

I have this application (it is written in Romanian):

[image]

I have made just the easy things for it, but my problem is that I don't know wich is the best methd for generating the invoice. Could anybody give me a good resource, and explanation based on it, please?

This is an invoice made by hand in Word. This is also how I want my invoices to look like:

[image]

BTW: I know my question has FLEXIBLE answers, but I need a starting point and something small beside it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. Can you clarify, maybe with an example?

Comment: Could you give more background what is invoice in your case, what do you want to do with invoice, like send it to customers with email or print it or save it somewhere. Do you need to keep history of invoices. etc?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks for your tip, I got the idea :) I also need something to help me with my problem.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta see in my edit, I hope now it is clear.

Comment: @Victor Can you provide more information about your specific requirements? What environment is this invoice to be generated in? And what have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: You might be able to use itextsharp, a library for generating pdfs. I have not used it though. http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Comment: @Clint, I am not a very good English speaker. What do you mean by envornment? If you mean what I think, then the invoice need to be a PDF.

Comment: @Victor where is the invoice generated? Is it generated by the application when your user clicks a button / does something or does the application ask a service or something else to generate the invoice for it?

Comment: the invoice has to be generated when the user clicks the button "Generare"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try crystal Reports as these are widely used to generate reports and invoices. Follow these links, may be they'll be helpful for you:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15859/Basics-of-Crystal-Report-for-NET-Programmers
- http://infynet.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/crystal-report-in-c/

Or you can google it for more tutorials, there are too many.

Comment: I am not yet sure about your links, but as I will start reading those pages I might find the right way to reach my goal. Thank you